# Exact same code (with multithreading) doesn't work on 2 different computers

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working at the moment on a simple Chess A.I. (calculate possible future turns, rate them, chosse the best one, + some tricks so you don't have to calculate every single turn). The code is written in Java and I'm using Netbeans. To make the calculations faster, I use multithreading. The code works roughly like this:

- Main function makes first some calculations and then starts 8 threads.
- the threads execute the main-calculations
- when they finish, they set a boolean value in a boolean array (finished[]) true. This array is in the "main Class" (if you call it like this), where also the main function is.
- during all this time the main function is waiting and checking constantly if every value of the finished[] - array is true. If that is the case, it continues it's work.

Now I have a strange problem. The code works perfectly on my PC, but when I run the EXACT same code on my laptop, the main function won't continue its work, after all values of the finished[]-array are true. I already made some changes in the code, so I can try it with different numbers of threads, but the result is always the same.

I have totally no idea what's going on here and would really appreciate it, if someone of you had any answers and/or suggestions!

If you need any more Information just ask, I'll try my best. :)

(Sorry for possible grammar mistakes, english isn't my native language, but I'm trying my best. ;))

So I was asked to show some Code I used in the program:

(Perhaps first a warning, yes I am still a big Noob in Java and this is my first time I work with threads so don't be shocked if you see terrible mistakes I possibly made. xD)

The main Class looks something like this:

```
public class Chess_ai_20 {

   static boolean finished[] = new boolean[8];
   Distributor[] Distributors = new Distributor[8];
   ...

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      boolean testing=false;
      ...
      //some calculations and other stuff
      ...
      Distributors[0] = new Distributor(...., "0"); //the String "0" will be the thread name.
      Distributors[1] = new ...
      ...
      Distributors[7] = new Distributor(...., "7");

      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          Distributoren[i].start();
       }

       testing=false;

       while(testing==false){
          if(finished[0]==true && finished[1]==true && ... && finished[7]==true){
             testing=true;   //That's the point where I get stuck I suppose
           }
        }

        System.out.println("I made it!");
   }

   public static void setFinished(int i) {
      finished[i] = true;
      System.out.println("finished [" + i + "] = " + finished[i]);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finished));   //To check how many values already are true
    }
 }
```

Then we got of course the class "Distributor"

```
public class Distributor extends Thread {
   Thread t;
   String threadname;
   boolean running=false;
   ...
   Distributor(......, String s) {
      threadname=s;
      ...
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void start() {
      running=true;
      if (t == null) {
          t = new Thread(this,threadname);
          t.start();
      }
    }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      if(running){
         ...
         //Do the main calculations etc.
         ...
         //All the Calculations habe been done at this point
         Chess_ai_20.setFinished(Character.getNumericValue(threadname.charAt(0))); //Set the value of finished[] true in the main class
         running=false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code. From your description, it looks like a race condition is likely to have happened.

Comment: You should post the code. My guess is that access to finished[] is not properly synchronized.

Comment: `volatile boolean[]` I  assume. Calling [`thread.join()s`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) would be another solution.

Comment: As mentioned by others without looking at any code its difficult to say.

Comment: @JoopEggen, rather than join eight threads, and then start eight new ones for each move, it would be better to teach the noob to use a thread pool.  The main routine could submit eight tasks, and then wait for the futures to complete.  It might not make any difference in a chess program, but it would serve the OP well in the future to get in the habit of pooling threads.

Comment: @jameslarge yes a {thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) I also felt mentioning. It is heavily used and allows more concurrency than just 8 threads. However one might think of Future, or whatever too. Worth for you to turn into an answer.

Comment: @asgs  Does this help?

Comment: @PeterL Does this help?

Comment: @Setu Does this help?

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks for the tip! Yes I am a Noob but I'm eager to increase my knowledge. I'll inform myself about thread pools.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for the tip and the link. Always happy to learn something new. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, using a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) would be much simpler and easy to understand. Below is a snippet demonstrating how you could rewrite your code. Check out the [code in action](http://ideone.com/uCq4UJ).

First, you write a `Callable` to define the task that you want to do.

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        // Do some job and return the result.
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}
```

And then, you submit this task to an [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). There are a lot of Executors in JDK. You want to go through the [Concurrency Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) first.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime
            .getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    List<Callable<Boolean>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++) {
        callables.add(new MyCallable());
    }

    List<Future<Boolean>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);
    for (Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
        System.out.println(future.get()); // You'd want to store this into an array or wherever you see fit.
    }

    executor.shutdown();
```

Remember that the [futures returned by the executor are in the same order as the `Callable`s you submitted (or added)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) to the `Collection` (in this case, an `ArrayList`). So you don't need to worry about returning the index, an ID or even the name of the `Thread` (if you assigned one) to map the corresponding result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great tutorial and the reference to the other documents! I changed my code and implicated your proposed system with a threadpool and the futures. The code works now successfully on both, my laptop and my pc! :) Wish you a great day and thanks again!